# Discrete measure theoretic model for Bernoulli sequence

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ be a countable set, $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ a sequence of non-negative numbers such that $\sum P_i=1$, and $\mu$ the measure $\mu(A)=\sum_{x_i=A}P_i$. Show that $X$ cannot contain an infinite sequence of independent sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ such that, for all $i$, $\mu(A_i)=\dfrac12$.

Assume that there exist such sets. Every point $x\in X$ must lie in one of the four sets $A_1\cap A_2,A_1^c\cap A_2,A_1\cap A_2^c,A_1^c\cap A_2^c$. The measure of the four sets is $\dfrac14$ each, by independence. So the measure of the set $\{x\}$ is less than $\dfrac14$. Proceeding similarly with $n$ sets, the measure of $\{x\}$ is less than $\dfrac1{2^n}$, so it must be $0$. But then $1=\mu(X)=\sum_{x_i\in X}P_i=0$, a contradiction.

Now, the exercise says that the moral is: A *discrete* measure theoretic model for the Bernoulli process does not exist.  Just let $A_i$ be the subset of $X$ corresponding to the event "an $H$ at the $i$th trial."

I don't understand this moral. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are given a probabilistic space $(X,\mu)$ together with a sequence of independent Bernoulli variables $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,\dots$
Now take $A_i = \{Z_i = 1\}$ for all $i \in \Bbb N$. This gives you an infinite sequence of independent events with $\mu(A_i)=\frac{1}{2}$, right?

The exercice proves that $X$ has to be uncountable.